# Google Cloud Platform API - list used zones for compute engines

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When you want to list some resources using the Google Cloud Api usually the zone is required.
E.g. if you wnat to list all VM instances you have to execute

```
compute.instances.list
-----------------------
GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{some project}/zones/{some zone}/instances?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This is cool if you know the zone in advance, but I would like to list all available zones, let the user choose a zone and then list all instances in that project and zone.

There is an endpoint that returns the zones for a given project:

```
compute.zones.list
------------------

GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{some project}/zones?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

but it returns all available zones, even the ones that you don't have any resource in.

Is there a way to get only the used zones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an API called aggregatedList that retrieves a list of all your instances in a project across all regions and all zones.  The documentation for this can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList

At the highest level, the REST request looks like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/aggregated/instances
```

Comment: I think that this will do the job. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is awesome! I've spend hours looking for something that does this.